# What can I do to convert my desktop Python Tkinter application to a web application?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, heroku, tkinter, web-deployment

What can I do to convert my desktop Python Tkinter application to a web application? to deploy on Heroku
Business logic is all in python. pytesseract, openCV2, pymongo
I will have to move the app to the web for others to share and use the app.
as simple as possible

thanks

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely have to rewrite the entire UI portion of the application. There is no simple way to serve up a tkinter application via a webserver.